# Is the dye used for diagnosing oil leaks harmful to an engine?

Tags: oil-leak

I have concluded that my engine has an oil leak and wish to find its source(s).  Upon research and reading several other answers on this site the most practical way to go about this appears to be using a uv dye additive in combination with a black light to pinpoint the areas causing my oil to leak.

It seems like a bad idea to go and start adding things to the oil system of a vehicle, for example if I was low on oil I wouldn't go adding water or some other liquid.

Can using the dye for diagnosis cause further damage to seals or other engine components and does it need to be flushed from the engine after the leak(s) are diagnosed?

Comment: I know that it's harmless (as long as you use the right formulation for your application), and I can tell you for certain that you can just leave it in until your next oil change, but I don't have enough info about the chemistry of these dyes to give a proper answer. All of these dyes are specifically formulated to be compatible with the fluids they're intended to be used in, and can be left in the system.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes this is completely fine and what the dye is designed for. You should be able to get a kit at your local auto-parts store.